# Customize DisplayAlert in Xamarin.Forms shared project

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I need to customize the **DisplayAlert** to can Add an image to the title, change background color and change buttons style.

How can I do this for Android & iOS?? Help me, please!
some like this

[image]